Android Studio Multiplayer Game w/ Firebase Join Code
I am currently developing a game that involves multiplayer connection through join codes (similar to Among Us), but am running into an issue. There is no outputted error, yet the application on each individual emulator is different. My MainActivity is my main screen that includes  "Create a Room" and "Join a Room" buttons. LobbyActivity has Gemini API generated truths or dares and displays the user's name.
MainActivity:
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button create_a_room;
    Button join_a_room;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference roomRef;
    String enteredcode = "";
    EditText username;
    String roomName;
    String playername;
    ArrayList<String> roomsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        create_a_room = findViewById(R.id.createButton);
        username = findViewById(R.id.userTxt);
        join_a_room = findViewById(R.id.joinButton);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        playername = prefs.getString("playerName", "");
        roomsList = new ArrayList<>();

        create_a_room.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!username.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                playername = username.getText().toString();
                roomName = generateJoinCode();
                roomRef = database.getReference("rooms").child(roomName);
                roomRef.setValue(playername + "'s Room").addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Room created. Join code: " + roomName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startLobbyActivity();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to create room", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        join_a_room.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alertsy, null);
            builder.setView(customLayout);

            builder.setMessage("Please enter the join code as shown on the room creator's device.")
                    .setTitle("Enter your code:")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Submit", (dialog, which) -> {
                        EditText editText = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                        enteredcode = editText.getText().toString();
                        if (!enteredcode.isEmpty() && !username.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                            playername = username.getText().toString();
                            roomRef = database.getReference("rooms").child(enteredcode);
                            addRoomEventListener(enteredcode);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a join code and username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        });
    }

    private void addRoomEventListener(String joinCode) {
        roomRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    startLobbyActivity();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid join code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to join room", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startLobbyActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LobbyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("playerName", playername);
        intent.putExtra("roomName", roomName);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private String generateJoinCode() {
        Random random = new Random();
        StringBuilder joinCode = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            joinCode.append((char) (random.nextInt(26) + 'A'));
        }
        return joinCode.toString();
    }
}

LobbyActivity
package com.example.mobile_final;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.ai.client.generativeai.GenerativeModel;
import com.google.ai.client.generativeai.java.GenerativeModelFutures;
import com.google.ai.client.generativeai.type.Content;
import com.google.ai.client.generativeai.type.GenerateContentResponse;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;


public class LobbyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView lobbyTextView;
    String recentResult = "";
    Button next;
    Button swipe;
    Button card;
    String players;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lobby);

        next = findViewById(R.id.next);
        swipe = findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        card = findViewById(R.id.backCard);
        lobbyTextView = findViewById(R.id.userName);

        String playerName = getIntent().getStringExtra("playerName");
        players += playerName + "\n";

        lobbyTextView.setText(players);
        next.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            GenerativeModel gm = new GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-flash", "API KEY");
            GenerativeModelFutures model = GenerativeModelFutures.from(gm);

            Content content = new Content.Builder()
                    .addText("Generate a new and spicy truth or dare prompt. Only return one prompt.")
                    .build();

            Executor executor = Runnable::run;

            ListenableFuture<GenerateContentResponse> response = model.generateContent(content);
            Futures.addCallback(response, new FutureCallback<GenerateContentResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(GenerateContentResponse result) {
                    String resultText = result.getText();
                    System.out.println(resultText);
                    card.setText(resultText);
                    recentResult = resultText;
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, executor);

        });

        swipe.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        });
    }
}


Thank you in advance!
I tried to print out a Toast that throws any errors, however it was to no avail.

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is with the code you shared. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.
